# Creating individual routes from home to multiple destinations in ArcMap ModelBuilder with ArcGIS Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst, route, closest-facility

I am trying to create individual routes from Homes to multiple Destinations. The unique ID is respondent in both the Homes and Destinations tables. I've created an iterative model in ModelBuilder where the Routes are calculated based on the RouteName in this case Respondent, the problem is that I have multiple destinations (stops) for many Respondents and when running the Route model, the model adds all the stops together to create one long route for that individual Respondent.

For example, I have Home stop, and I want to calculate the routes from Home stop, Respondent 101 to multiple Destination stops that have the same Respondent 101 ID.

Can you help/advise what to change in the model to make it do this?

See the photos attached. I've got lots of data and want my model to iterate through the list of Homes, create a route with multiple paired destinations and then output to one file. The attribute table shows the Route analysis has worked but only with paired data that has 2 stops only, it didn't work for multiple stops.

[image: Attribute_table_of_route]

[image: Route_model]

Comment: Sounds like it is to do with how you are running the add locations tool. I think the default is to append when you want to overwrite the stops. Suggest you read the help file for this tool to explore the parameters.

Comment: I checked out the add locations tool and changed the default append, did't fix the problem... still open to new suggestions :)